# iOS - Unable to Upload media with Twitter/Fabric New SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-rest-api

I want to post a photo to twitter from my iOS app. I can post a tweet without media but when i am trying to attach media it throws an error.

I am following twitter documentation and according to that first I need to upload media to https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json and then I will be able to attach it with the tweet using media-id.

here is my code for uploading media.

App is crashing at URLRequestWithMedthod call.

Help me to resolve issue.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shareit.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7);
NSString *statusesShowEndpoint = @"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json";
NSDictionary *params = @{@"media" : imageData};
NSError *clientError;
NSURLRequest *request = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient] 
                         URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                         URL:statusesShowEndpoint
                         parameters:params
                         error:&clientError];

if (request) {
    [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
     sendTwitterRequest:request
     completion:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                  NSData *data,
                  NSError *connectionError) {
         if (data) {
             // handle the response data e.g.
             NSError *jsonError;
             NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                   JSONObjectWithData:data
                                   options:0
                                   error:&jsonError];
             NSLog(@"%@",json);
         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", connectionError);
         }
     }];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", clientError);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well it was pretty simple. All was missing is conversion of imagedata into base64EncodedString. Here is the solution.

```
   NSString *media = @"https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json";

   NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9);

   NSString *imageString = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
   NSError *error;
   NSURLRequest *request = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient] URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URL:media parameters:@{@"media":imageString} error:&error];

   [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient] sendTwitterRequest:request completion:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

       NSError *jsonError;
       NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:data
                              options:0
                              error:&jsonError];
       NSLog(@"Media ID :  %@",[json objectForKey:@"media_id_string"]);

      // Post tweet With media_id
    }];
```

Comment: Did this actually work for you? I'm trying this and getting 503 Service Unavailable. How did you get this to work without oauth_* params?

Comment: @sun it will not work without oauth_* params. You need to login before using this.

Comment: Worked for me , Thanks !

Comment: how works that with multiple images? can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559534/upload-multiple-photos-to-twitter-using-fabric

Answer (score 1):

Completing the Saani's answer

```
// Post tweet With media_id

mediaID = [json objectForKey:@"media_id_string"];
client = [[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient];
message = @{@"status": title, @"wrap_links": @"true", @"media_ids": mediaID};

NSURLRequest *request = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URL:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json" parameters:message error:&error];

[client sendTwitterRequest:request completion:^(NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable connectionError) {

    if (connectionError) {
        NSLog(@"error %@",[connectionError localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSError *jsonError;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
        NSLog(@"json Finish! %@",json);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the swift 2.2 (Xcoe 7.3.2) code if anyone is still looking for help.

```
 let client = TWTRAPIClient.init(userID:<Twitter_User_Id_Here>)
let imgData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named:"Home")!, 0.7)
    client.uploadMedia(imgData!, contentType: "image/jpeg", completion: {(media_ids,error) in

        if error == nil{
            //prints the media_ids in String. 
      //Pass them into the params of status update params ["media_ids":<MEDIA_ID>]
            print(media_ids)
        }
        else{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
```

To Send with status update.

```
   let request = client.URLRequestWithMethod("POST", URL: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json", parameters: ["status":"Hello World","media_ids":<Media_Ids_Here>], error: nil)

    client.sendTwitterRequest(request, completion: {
        (response,data,error)in
        if error == nil {
            print(data)

        }
        else{
            print("Error")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 latest

**install pod file pod 'TwitterKit'**

```
import TwitterKit
```

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-init.html

```
func PostTweetToTwitter() {
        let twitter_USERID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Constants.Twitter.TWITTER_USER_ID)

        let url = URL(string: "http://www.tinyeyeimage.com/picture/Photos/149802345.png")
        let tweetImage = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)

        let tweetString = "Welcome to the Twitter world!!"

        let uploadUrl = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json"
        let updateUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"

        let imageString = tweetImage?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions())


        let client = TWTRAPIClient.init(userID: twitter_USERID)

        let requestUploadUrl = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "POST", urlString: uploadUrl, parameters: ["media": imageString], error: nil)

        client.sendTwitterRequest(requestUploadUrl) { (urlResponse, data, connectionError) -> Void in
            if connectionError == nil {
                if let mediaDict = self.dataToJSON(data: (data! as NSData) as Data) as? [String : Any] {
                    let media_id = mediaDict["media_id_string"] as! String
                    let message = ["status": tweetString, "media_ids": media_id]

                    let requestUpdateUrl = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "POST", urlString: updateUrl, parameters: message, error: nil)

                    client.sendTwitterRequest(requestUpdateUrl, completion: { (urlResponse, data, connectionError) -> Void in
                        if connectionError == nil {
                            if let _ = self.dataToJSON(data: (data! as NSData) as Data) as? [String : Any] {
                                print("Upload suceess to Twitter")
                            }
                        }

                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```